# method from python convert to C#

Tags: c#, python, hash

i have a method that i need to remake in C# based on this python code.

```
def _generateHash(self, password, time_stamp, nonce):
    import hashlib
    shaPw = hashlib.sha1()
    shaPw.update( password )
    m = hashlib.sha1()
    m.update(str(time_stamp))
    m.update(nonce)
    m.update(shaPw.hexdigest())
    m.update(self.api_key_secret)
    return m.hexdigest()
```

hashing in C# is allot different compared to python. also my hashing experience is not that great. is there anybody that can help me?

this is wat i have right now.

```
    private string GenerateHash(string password, double timeStamp, string nonce)
    {
        using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            var pwHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            using (SHA1Managed sha1total = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                sha1total.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timeStamp.ToString()));
                sha1total.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonce));

                string hexaHashPW = "";
                foreach (byte b in pwHash)
                {
                    hexaHashPW += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
                }

                sha1total.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexaHashPW));
                sha1total.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_SecretApiKey));

                var hmac = new HMACSHA1();

                //string hexaHashTotal = "";
                //foreach (byte b in sha1total.Hash)
                //{
                //    hexaHashTotal += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
                //}
                hmac.ComputeHash(sha1total.Hash);
                var hexaHashTotal = hmac.Hash;
                var endhash = BitConverter.ToString(hexaHashTotal).Replace("-", "");
                return endhash;

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Passing in `time_stamp` as a double then just using `str()` is a very bad idea. You are entirely depending on Python and C# generating the same string representation from the same double, and that representation remaining the same from one version of Python/C# to another. Python 2.7 will round your timestamp to 2 decimals, Python 3 will round it to as many significant digits as are needed.

Answer (score 0):

after even more research and trail and error i found the way to produce the same hash as the python code.

this is the answer for others that have problems with this.

```
    private string GenerateHash(string password, double timeStamp, string nonce)
    {
        using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            var pwHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            using (SHA1Managed sha1total = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                string hexaHashPW = "";
                foreach (byte b in pwHash)
                {
                    hexaHashPW += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
                }

                var hmacPW = new HMACSHA1();
                hmacPW.ComputeHash(pwHash);

                sha1total.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timeStamp.ToString() + nonce + hexaHashPW + _SecretApiKey));
                var hmac = new HMACSHA1();

                string hexaHashTotal = "";
                foreach (byte b in sha1total.Hash)
                {
                    hexaHashTotal += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
                }
                hmac.ComputeHash(sha1total.Hash);
                return hexaHashTotal.ToLower();

            }
        }


    }
```